# As a part of initial load testing or incremental load testing do we validate audit fields?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse, uat

We are performing initial load testing and incremental load testing on target tables in datawarehouse. so do we validate audit field values in initial load test or do we validate audit fields values  in incremental load testing ? As part of which testing do we validate audit field values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably audit fields get populated in both initial and incremental loads, in which case you need to test them in both types of load

Comment: Yea , thanks for the answer ✌